# Adding pan gesture to multiple dynamically created views?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering what the best way to do this would be.  I'm creating a new imageview on a button click.  This view needs to have a pan gesture recogniser attached.

I've been unable to get this to work.  It has to be dynamic as the user needs to be able to create multiple views.

My code so far:

Button click method:

```
UIImageView *myView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg.png"]];
myView.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50);
myView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[self.view addSubView:myView];

UIGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:myView action:@selector(moveView:)];
[myView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

The moveView method simply changes the center position of the new view.

The view is created fine but when I try to move the view, I receive an 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error.

What is the correct way to do this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the moveView: method is implemented in your controller since myView is of type UIImageView.
By calling

```
UIGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:myView action:@selector(moveView:)];
```

you tell the newly created gesture recognizer to fire the moveView: method in myView.

try

`UIGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveView:)];`

to call the moveView: method in self (your controller?) rather than in myView

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the selector (methods) "moveView:" to your myView what doesn't implement. (doesn't respond to this selector). You need to change in order to send to your viewController, here is:

```
  UIGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveView:)];
```

One thing is the view to add the gesture, another the object what fire the methods.